# How would a Dragonborn (or Dragon) refer to its own breath weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, roleplaying, lore

I'm currently running a DnD 5e campaign in a homebrew setting where Dragons and Half-dragons are the main antagonists. I am planning a non-combat encounter where the group meets a Half-dragon that threatens them with it's breath weapon. But having him say something along the lines of "I'll get you with my Breath Weapon!" or "Watch out or I'll breathe on you!" seems unwieldy.

So, how would a half-dragon, or a full dragon for that matter, refer to its own Breath Weapon? How have you phrased this in your games, so it sounds better? Are there examples of better phrasing in the game literature?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A breath weapon is a tool to achieve a purpose, so probably they *wouldn't*. They'd threaten to do something more specific with it, instead.

So, none of these:

> - Watch out or I'll sword you!
> - I'll get you with my dagger!
> - Watch out or I'll breathe on you!

But instead, more like these:

> - Are you truly so ready to die? *rests hand on sword hilt*
> - I'll give you a second smile! *draws dagger*
> - I will roast you and crack your smoking bones. *said while flames glow behind teeth*
> - Freeze where you are, or I won't *ask* anymore. *frost suddenly forms around head*

(Adjust for taste and tolerance of puns, of course.)

If they have a cultural, religious, or pet name for their breath weapon, that'd be an interesting setting detail a DM could add to their world, but still something that's unlikely to be referred to directly in a threat. It would be akin to someone calling their sword “Bloodheart” or something, and always mentioning its name when threatening people — drawing attention to its name at the slightest opportunity would come off as an unusual affectation of that *specific* NPC, rather than natural dialogue that most people with a named weapon would use.

Comment: When you put it this way it makes a lot more sense. No one really refers to their weapon directly. I guess another question is, in a more general sense, would Dragons or Half-dragons/Dragonborn have a name for the ability to breathe fire/acid/etc.? Maybe they would revere the ability as a gift from the creator or something?

Haha, my tolerance for puns is pretty high.

Answer (score 11):

My preference is to refer to the damage type from the breath weapon. Examples,

- "I'll burn you alive"
- "I'll melt your flesh from your bones"
- "It'll give you quite... a shock."
- "You'll die gasping"
- "Do you know what happens to a toad when it's struck by lightning?"

Though a general purpose, "I'll kill you", works just fine if you don't feel like telegraphing their type.

Comment: George: "Anyone up for some BBQ?" *puffs smoke*

Comment: Blue Half Dragon: "Hey dude, want to do the sixty-hertz shuffle?"